# Access files from a location in Android

Tags: java, android, android-file, android-storage

I am trying to access(only read) the list of files available in a location in android device using below code but I am getting null as a response. Please correct me if I am missing something. I tried the below code in Android 11 and I am expecting it should work from Android 9 onwards.

```
File[] files = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MyApp/files/").listFiles();
```

I am getting null for the above code. Also I add the below permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also having the permission granting request in code as well and added the below attribute in the application tag in AndroidManifest.

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

After adding all the above still I am facing the issue to get the files from the given location.
Am I doing it in a right way? My objective is to access the files after the application is launched and these files will be added manually into the location by user using ADB commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this way

for internal files (/data/data)

```java
File[] files = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().listFiles();
```

for external files (/sdcard)

```java
File[] files =  getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDirs("your path");
```

Comment: Thank you Rolland. I Used getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("").listFiles().